# wkhtmltopdf Error "No such file or directory" (Django)

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf to create a PDF from HTML code. I have used xhtml2pdf and pisa but I have had problems with css styles. well, wkhtmltopdf is my last option.

I have followed this steps.  https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf

```
sudo aptitude install libfontconfig
pip install django-wkhtmltopdf
```

and if I add 'wkhtmltopdf' to my INSTALLED_APPS it will recognize the wkhtmltopdf path.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ["wkhtmltopdf"]
```

Well, when I try to generate a PDF generate an error.

this is my code:

```
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse 

 context = {
            'linkedin1':self.linkedin1,
            'twitter1':self.twitter1,
            'facebook1':self.facebook1,
            'current': get_current_base_url,
           }


    html_path = "app/folder/page1_1.html"
    response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                   template=html_path,
                                   filename="hello.pdf",
                                   context= context,
                                   show_content_in_browser=False,
                                   cmd_options=settings.WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS,
                                   )
```

In settings:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS = {
'quiet': True,
}
```

My error:

```
 File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 136, in get_response
response = response.render()
 File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 104, in render
self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py", line 144, in rendered_content
footer_filename=footer_filename)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py", line 103, in convert_to_pdf
return wkhtmltopdf(pages=[filename], **cmd_options)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 92, in wkhtmltopdf
return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think it cant't find 'wkhtmltopdf'.

My wkhtmltopdf install path is:

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/
```

well I add in settings:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/'
```

To find the wkhtmltopdf's and appers "path permission denied"

What is wrong?, what is missing?, what is the problem?.

I am using:
Ububtu server 12.04/64 bits, 
Django 1.4, 
Pyrhon 2.7,

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT 1:**

I fixed mi problem doing that following this tutorial

http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/crear-pdf-en-django-y-virtualenv-c110664l/

```
apt-get build-dep libqt4-gui libqt4-network libqt4-webkit
apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg git-core git-doc libssl-dev wkhtmltopdf
```

in settings

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
```

But appered new error:

```
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/template/response.py", line 104, in render
self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py", line 144, in rendered_content
footer_filename=footer_filename)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/views.py", line 103, in convert_to_pdf
return wkhtmltopdf(pages=[filename], **cmd_options)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/utils.py", line 92, in wkhtmltopdf
return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf', '--encoding', u'utf8', '--quiet', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfE_THjv.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status
```

**Solved:**

----------- July 14 -----------

0) Create a ~/tmp/ directory and change into it

```
cd ~
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
```

1) libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2 and wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2  from  http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

```
 wget https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2

 wget https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

2) Create subfolders and move the files into them:

```
 mkdir libwkhtmltox
 mkdir wkhtmltopdf

 mv libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2 libwkhtmltox
 mv wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2 wkhtmltopdf
```

3) go in folders previously created and unzip the files.

```
 cd libwkhtmltox
 tar -xvjf libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2 
 cd ../wkhtmltopdf
 tar -xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

4) access to ‘lib’. there we find a file named  ‘libwkhtmltox.so’, then move it

```
cd ../libwkhtmltox/lib/
sudo cp libwkhtmltox.so /usr/local/lib/
```

5) access to include, there we find a folder named ‘wkhtmltox’, then move it

```
cd ../include/
sudo cp -avr wkhtmltox/ /usr/local/include/
```

6) after unzip the files we find the file “wkhtmltopdf-amd64”, move it.

```
cd ../../wkhtmltopdf/
sudo cp wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/bin/
```

7) I was following this post. http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/crear-pdf-en-django-y-virtualenv-c110664l/

8) install

```
sudo aptitude install libfontconfig

sudo apt-get build-dep libqt4-gui libqt4-network libqt4-webkit 

sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg git-core git-doc libssl-dev wkhtmltopdf
```

9) I was following this post, https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf

10) later install the application

```
 pip install django-wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: I don't currently have a throwaway Django app on which I can try to reproduce this problem; however, if I were trying to debug it, the first thing I'd check is whether Django thinks the template file exists. e.g., Try adding `import os.path` to the top of the view, and printing `os.path.exists(html_path)` before the `return`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Brian Clapper. "os.path.exists" is for absolute path, i am using relative paths, well, if I change something in html path the error is "TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(not_found))", then the html path is not the problem.

Comment: FYI, `os.path.exists()` is not just for an absolute path. It works with relative paths.

Comment: Ok, "os.path.exists()" returned 'False' but the html path didn throw 'TemplateDoesNotExist' error, then, I think the path is correct.

Comment: do you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I have 64 bits SO and I have installed for 32 bits, you have to check it and replace some files.

I add extra information in my post.

Comment: You can answer your own question instead of editing it and pasting your solution. Answer your own question, and then accept your answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it following the next steps:

0) Create a ~/tmp/ directory and change into it

```
cd ~ 
mkdir tmp 
cd tmp
```

1) libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2 and wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2 from http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

```
wget https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2

wget https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

2) Create subfolders and move the files into them:

```
mkdir libwkhtmltox 
mkdir wkhtmltopdf

mv libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2 libwkhtmltox 
mv wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2 wkhtmltopdf
```

3) go in folders previously created and unzip the files.

```
cd libwkhtmltox tar -xvjf libwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-amd64.tar.bz2 
cd   ../wkhtmltopdf tar -xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

4) access to ‘lib’. there we find a file named ‘libwkhtmltox.so’, then move it

```
cd ../libwkhtmltox/lib/ 
sudo cp libwkhtmltox.so /usr/local/lib/
```

5) access to include, there we find a folder named ‘wkhtmltox’, then move it

```
cd ../include/ 
sudo cp -avr wkhtmltox/ /usr/local/include/
```

6) after unzip the files we find the file “wkhtmltopdf-amd64”, move it.

```
cd ../../wkhtmltopdf/ 
sudo cp wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/bin/
```

7) I was following this post. http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/crear-pdf-en-django-y-virtualenv-c110664l/

8) install

```
sudo aptitude install libfontconfig

sudo apt-get build-dep libqt4-gui libqt4-network libqt4-webkit

sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg git-core git-doc libssl-dev wkhtmltopdf
```

9) I was following this post, https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf

10) later install the application

```
pip install django-wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf, solved my problem.....thanks

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem after a linux upgrade. I found the solution at this link: https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/issues/75

In my case, the basic solution is find out where wkhtmltopdf is stored using `which`:

```
$ which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Then add the following line to `settings.py`:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

(i.e. the location returned by which)

N.B. If `which wkhtmltopdf` returns blank, you probably haven’t properly installed wkhtmltopdf. You can do so from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: I have searched for this solution for five freakin' days. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution: on top of your pip install, just install the relevant version of wkhtmltopdf binary from here: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html. In my case, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest Solution for this problem:

Download binary version of **wkhtmltopdf** as per your operation system

[Wkhtmltopdf binary file download link](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Add below coding in `settings.py` of your project.

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD_OPTIONS = {
    'quiet': True,
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Can someone explain what {'quiet': True} does? Thanks!

Comment: @BrendanMetcalfe {'quiet': True} means *Be less verbose*